# Ionic 3 background mode return as false

Tags: ionic-framework

I use Ionic 3 and I want my app to work in the background as well, and now I try to use background mode of Ionic 3 in app.component, using this.backgroundMode.enable() and then use method isEnable() but when I use isEnable() it return as false. What did I do wrong, why is it return as false? Please help me

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {

      this.backgroundMode.enable()
      var bgmStatus = this.backgroundMode.isEnabled();
      console.log(bgmStatus);

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}

   

    import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
    
    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'app.html'
    })
    
    export class MyApp {
      rootPage: any = HomePage;
    
      constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
    
          this.backgroundMode.enable()
          var bgmStatus = this.backgroundMode.isEnabled();
          console.log(bgmStatus);
    
          statusBar.styleDefault();
          splashScreen.hide();
        });
      }
    }
```